# Delete with subquery using jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to use jooq to process this SQL instruction (listName is a List < String >) :

```sql
DELETE FROM table_calendar cal
WHERE cal.client_id
IN (
SELECT client.id FROM table_client client
JOIN cal 
ON cal.client_id = client.id
WHERE client.name = :listName )
```

I wrote this proposal :

```java
    SelectConditionStep<Record1<String>> res = create.select(CALENDAR.CLIENT_ID)
                        .from(CALENDAR)
                        .join(CLIENT)
                        .on(CLIENT.ID.eq(CALENDAR.ID))
                        .where(CLIENT.NAME.in(listName));

    Query deleteQuery = create.delete(CALENDAR)
                    .where(CALENDAR.ID.in(res.getBindValues()));

    create.batch(deleteQuery).execute();
```

is it a correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no batch query involved in your statement. Also, I'm not sure why you need to join the `calendar` table in your subquery. Here's an alternative SQL query:

```sql
DELETE FROM calendar
WHERE client_id IN (
    SELECT client.id
    FROM client
    WHERE client.name = :listName
)
```

Which translates to the following jOOQ query

```java
create.delete(CALENDAR)
      .where(CALENDAR.CLIENT_ID.in(
           select(CLIENT.ID)
          .from(CLIENT)
          .where(CLIENT.NAME.eq(listName))
      ))
      .execute();
```

The above jOOQ query (as always) assumes you're static importing this:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: yes, the joint is useless. Thanks for your response